# Export figure to TIFF with specific format parameters

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to export figures for a paper that adhere to a journal's requirements, which are: `TIFF` format, figure's `width=180mm`, `resolution=900 dpi` and `compression="lzw"`. I have tried various ways to export and the one below seems to be the best one to honor both resolution and size. However, the script I wrote does not export the image properly.

```
# sample data
data <- data.frame(x=gl(2,50), y=rnorm(100))

# the graph
p <- ggplot(data, aes(x, y)) + geom_boxplot()
p

#sizes are in inches (180mm=7.087inches).
dpi = 900
tiff(".../test.tiff", width = 7,087*dpi, height = 3.825*dpi, compression="lzw", units="px", res=dpi)
p
dev.off()
```

Note: The figure export works well when I lower the width value to `width = 6.654*dpi` but that doesn't conform to the requirements.

Comment: There is a typo. It should be `7.087`.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you simply specify the width in mm?

```
dpi = 900
tiff("test.tiff", width = 180, height = 240, 
     compression="lzw", units="mm", res=dpi)
p
dev.off()
```